# Cloudflare adds too much latency to API calls

Tags: cloudflare, latency

Trying out cloudflare for ddos protection of an SPA webapp, using free tier for testing.
Static contents loading is fine, but API calls became very slow.

From original <50ms for each api call to around 450~500ms each.
My apis are called via a subdomain eg apiXXX.mydomain.xyz

Any idea the problems or alternative fast ddos protection solution?

Comment: Yu should precise in your question what kind of API you're using (XML SOAP ? REST ? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare has created a page to explain the configuration you have to do when proxyfing APIs :

You have to create a new Page Rule in which you have to bypass cache, turn off Always Online and Browser Integrity Check options.
If you do not configure this, you may have slow response time because all those options are enabled by default on API calls.

Here's the link to create the configuration : [Cloudflare Page Rule for API](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-Cloudflare-with-your-API)